# Fastest way to create a numpy matrix with multiples of a vector

Tags: python, numpy

Let x,y be two numpy arrays of N elements. I want to create a numpy matrix whose columns are scaled-shifted versions of x. For instance, say

```
m=[0.2, 0.4, 1.2]
```

Then I want the matrix

> `X = [0.2x+y, 0.4x+y, 1.2x+y]`

What's the fastest (easiest as well, easiest being second priority) way to do this.

Currently I am doing something like this.

```
ListVec = [m[i]*x+y for i in numpy.arange(len(m))]
X = numpy.array(ListVec).T
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np 
m = np.array([0.2, 0.4, 1.2])
x = 5
y = 3
X = m*x+y
```

This is called [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) in numpy (both easy and fast ;))

Comment: `x` and `y` are arrays, not scalars.

Comment: @hpaulj I am not sure about that. OP has not indicated that and from the description, it seems OP is looking for scalars. You and CTZhu have covered the array cases too anyways though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use [Einstein Summation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for case when X and Y are arrays

```
In [70]: Y
Out[76]: array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [71]: X
Out[71]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [72]: m
Out[72]: [0.2, 0.4, 1.2]

In [73]: np.einsum('i,j', X, m)
Out[73]: 
array([[0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0.2, 0.4, 1.2],
       [0.4, 0.8, 2.4],
       [0.6, 1.2, 3.6],
       [0.8, 1.6, 4.8]])

In [74]: Y[...,np.newaxis] + np.einsum('i,j', X, m)
Out[74]: 
array([[ 5. ,  5. ,  5. ],
       [ 6.2,  6.4,  7.2],
       [ 7.4,  7.8,  9.4],
       [ 8.6,  9.2, 11.6],
       [ 9.8, 10.6, 13.8]])
```

Answer (score 1):

It would have helped if you'd given example `x` and `y` as well as `m`, but:

```
In [435]: x,y = np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array([.1,.2,.3,.4])
In [436]: m = [.2,.4,1.2]
```

So the result is (3,N):

```
In [437]: np.array([i*x+y for i in m])
Out[437]: 
array([[0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2],
       [0.5, 1. , 1.5, 2. ],
       [1.3, 2.6, 3.9, 5.2]])
```

broadcasting with `m`:

```
In [438]: np.array(m)[:,None]*x + y
Out[438]: 
array([[0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2],
       [0.5, 1. , 1.5, 2. ],
       [1.3, 2.6, 3.9, 5.2]])
```

oops, I missed your transpose,

```
In [440]: np.array(m)*x[:,None] + y[:,None]
Out[440]: 
array([[0.3, 0.5, 1.3],
       [0.6, 1. , 2.6],
       [0.9, 1.5, 3.9],
       [1.2, 2. , 5.2]])
```

I'd go ahead a apply the transpose to [438]